# HTML5 Drag and drop. Detecting where element was grabbed

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I am working with HTML 5 Drag and Drop API, and implementing sortable list and auto scroll. For some of features, I would like to able to detect which part of element was grabbed

Here is the illustration

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: When you say, which part of an element is clicked, what kind of result are you looking for back? X,Y coordinates? a javascript element?

Comment: or do you mean, top half or bottom half of the element??

Comment: @perrinprograms I was looking for scalar number representing distance from point of grab to the edge of the grabbed element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the computed padding+width of the element and the `offsetX` property of the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) to calculate the selected region.

```
yourElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function onDragStart(event){
  let width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(yourElement).getPropertyValue('width'));
  let padding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(yourElement).getPropertyValue('padding-left'));
  let position = event.offsetX;
  let middle = (width / 2) + padding;

  if (position <= middle) {
    console.log('left');
  } else {
    console.log('right');
  }
});
```

See this jsfiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/c23Lu6gy/28/